# Проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

Текст из js выводится некорректно

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Сам документ тоже в utf-8

и в документе .htaccess

```
AddCharset utf-8 .js
```

Выборка из БД тоже в кодировке utf-8

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: да, конечно, все документы в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM

Answer (score 0):

В заголовке страницы

```
<meta name="http-equiv" content="Content-type: text/html"; charset="utf-8">
```

При объявлении скрипта

```
<script src="" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

В .htaccess

```
AddCharset utf-8 .js
```

Вместо utf8 устанавливайте свою кодировку.

Comment: все что вы описали у меня уже прописано

Comment: попробуйте, charset="utf-8" вот так написать(надо обренуть в двойные кавычки)

Comment: попробовал, но проблема все равно осталась..

Comment: Может виновато то, что сам документ имеет отличную кодировку. Если Вы работаете в Notepad++, то внизу справа есть название кодировки текущего документа (например, ANSI). Если Вы ставите в мета-теге UTF-8, а сам документ написан в ANSI, то сделайте преобразование в UTF-8 (через меню "Кодировки" и пункт "Преобразовать в UTF-8 без BOM"). И убедитесь, что все Ваши таблицы и поля написаны в одной кодировке,

Comment: все снова проверил, везде стоит кодировка UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
...
```

Попробуйте добавить в самое начало страницы

Comment: Встречалась такая проблема при переносе на др. сервер. Вероятно дело в его конфигах